# No qualifying bean of type 'com.milkdairy.dao.userRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am new in spring boot and I am getting some error while compiling the code. Please help me to solve the error.

*I had done this forgot password implementation from a video from youtube. At that video he was doing this in thymeleaf and I am doing this in jsp. if this is the problem then please tell me the correct way to do this in jsp*

**Case** :- I was trying to implement the forgot password functionallity and while doing that I got this error

First of all, here's my error which I got

Error Log :

```
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1353)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.milkdairy.dao.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721)
    ... 30 more

Sep 14, 2021 4:05:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/spring-crud-rest-api] threw load() exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.milkdairy.dao.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.milkdairy.dao.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:758)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:676)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:545)        
    ...
```

When I put @Autowired to userRepository then the application crash at the starting and when I remove the @Autowired then the error is coming when I click on verify

ForgotController.java :

```
@Controller
public class ForgotController {

    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    int min = 1001;
    int max = 9999;

    @RequestMapping("/forgot")
    public String openEmailForm() {

        return "forgot/forgot_email_form";

    }

    @PostMapping("/send-otp")
    public String SendOTP(@RequestParam("email") String email, HttpSession session) {

        int otp = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

        System.out.println(otp);

        String subject = "OTP FROM Milk Dairy";
        String message = "" + "<div style='border:1px solid #e2e2e2; padding:20px;'>" + "<h1>" + "Otp is " + "<b>" + otp
                + "</n>" + "</h1>" + "</div>";
        String to = email;

        boolean flag = this.emailService.sendEmail(subject, message, to);

        if (flag) {

            session.setAttribute("otp", otp);
            session.setAttribute("email", email);
            return "forgot/verify_otp";

        } else {

            session.setAttribute("message", "Check your email id !!");

            return "forgot/forgot_email_form";
        }

    }

    @PostMapping("/verify-otp")
    public String verifyOtp(@RequestParam("otp") int otp, HttpSession session) {

        int myOtp = (int) session.getAttribute("myotp");
        String email = (String) session.getAttribute("email");

        if (myOtp == otp) {

            User user = this.userRepository.getUserByUserName(email);

            if (user == null) {

                session.setAttribute("message", "User does not existt with this email");

                return "forgot/forgot_email_form";

            } else {


                return "forgot/password_change_form";

            }

        } else {

            session.setAttribute("message", "You have entered wrong otp");

            return "forgot/verify-otp";
        }

    }

}
```

UserRepository.java :

```
package com.milkdairy.dao;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.milkdairy.entity.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("from User where userEmail=:uEmail")
    public User getUserByUserName(@Param("email") String email);
    

}
```

user.java :

```
package com.milkdairy.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name = "phone_no")
    private String phoneNo;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String userName, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNo, String email) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public User(String userName, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNo, String email,
            Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
        this.email = email;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", userName=" + userName + ", password=" + password + ", firstName=" + firstName
                + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", phoneNo=" + phoneNo + ", email=" + email + ", roles=" + roles + "]";
    }


}
```

everything is working fine but when I put the otp and click on verify then I am getting error

What am I misssing?

If I had done any mistake then please tell me..

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Please specify in which package is your *main* class containing the `@SpringBootAppplication` annotation.  UserRepository.java must be in a sub-package of that package, in order to be scanned.

Comment: Show me your `main` class

Comment: For more help see this. This is the full project repo : https://github.com/AniketPotdar-AP/MilkDairy